# Python Contains in Panda DATAFRAME

Tags: python, dataframe

I am grouping in each iteration the same price, add quantity together and combine the name of the exchange like :

```
     asks_price  asks_qty exchange_name_ask     bids_price  bids_qty exchange_name_bid
0    20156.51  0.000745          Coinbase      20153.28  0.000200          Coinbase
1    20157.52  0.050000          Coinbase      20152.27  0.051000          Coinbase
2    20158.52  0.050745          CoinbaseFTX   20151.28  0.051200       KrakenCoinbase
```

but to build orderbook i have to drop each time the row of one of the provider to update it so i do :

```
self.global_orderbook = self.global_orderbook[
                self.global_orderbook.exchange_name_ask != name]
```

And then i have with Coinbase for example

```
     asks_price  asks_qty exchange_name_ask     bids_price  bids_qty exchange_name_bid
0    20158.52  0.050745          CoinbaseFTX   20151.28  0.051200       KrakenCoinbase
```

But i want that KrakenCoinbase also leave
so I want to do something like :

```
            self.global_orderbook = self.global_orderbook[name not in self.global_orderbook.exchange_name_ask]
```

It doesnt work
I already try with contains but i cant on a series

```
self.global_orderbook = self.global_orderbook[self.global_orderbook.exchange_name_ask.contains(name)]
but 
'Series' object has no attribute 'contains'
```

Thanks for help

Comment: I want to do not in , in condition of a dataframe to be clear ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that we can use astype(str)
like :

```
self.global_orderbook = self.global_orderbook[self.global_orderbook.exchange_name_ask.astype(str).str.contains(name,regex=False)]
```

And then it works we can use on column with string